# bash exit code out of range

Tags: bash, exit

I'm a bit confused about these kinds of Bash exit codes.
For example:

# (exit 444)
then when I use echo command to show exit code:

# echo $?
   this is gonna result it : 188

It seems that it is a result from 444-256.I know that exit codes range is 0-255.So they will count as 256 exit codes in total.

But when I use:

```
(exit 555)
```

what calculation occurs? This returns 43 as exit code.

Comment: `555 - (2 * 256) = 43`, or  `555 % 256 = 43`

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing the effect of 8-bit integer overflow. After 255 (all 8 bits set) comes 0 (no bits set).

So the calculation you're seeing is "exit code modulo 256".

From the Bash manual, emphasis mine:

> **Exit Status**
>
> The exit status of an executed command is the value returned by the waitpid system call or equivalent function. **Exit statuses fall between 0 and 255**, though, as explained below, the shell may use values above 125 specially. Exit statuses from shell builtins and compound commands are also limited to this range. **Under certain circumstances, the shell will use special values to indicate specific failure modes**.

The last part becomes important once signals come into play, which may interrupt a process and give an exit code of...

> ...128+n if the command is terminated by signal n...

...but that's the shell at work, not the `exit` command (which does not allow those values).